# Finding locus of points $N$ outside a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ for which $[ABN]- [CDN] = k$

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, area, locus

Suppose we are given a positive number $k$ and a quadrilateral
$ABCD$ in which $AB$ and $CD$ are not parallel. Find the locus of points N OUTSIDE $ABCD$ for which $[ABN]- [CDN] = k$.

Note: $[ABN]$ denotes the area of triangle $ABN$.

(You may assume that $ABCD$ is convex for simplicity)

This was given as a "comment" in a book and I was wondering how to prove it.
Any help is appreciated, thank you

Updated on 25 March: As requested, please find the piece of the lecture note I have for that part in image here (sorry for late reply as sometimes I am not checking this, fyi):

[image: Piece of the Lecture Note I have]

Comment: Which book? Please edit the question to cite the book.

Comment: Ohh I just saw your comment and edited it accordingly as requested with full solution with the "observation" part I am having trouble with circled in "red".